# Can't access shared folder from Virtual Machine

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, windows-10, shared-folders

My desktop has Windows 10, I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTs on VirtualBox and on the vm settings I have set a shared folder

[image]

When I try to access the shared folder from Ubuntu I get this error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu, you need to add your username to the **vboxsf** group, using the adduser/addgroup command in terminal (`sudo adduser <username> vboxsf`), then logout and log back in, or reboot.